# Text Animation Timing Issues for Type and Erase Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, race-condition

I have created functions to type and erase text animation effect in JS. But, I'm stuck as to how to call the erase function only after the type function is fully executed? I've tried `setTimeout` which didn't seem to work. Help appreciated!

```
var clength = 0;var caption = 'MyName';var x = 1;var y = x/2;


$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('cursorAnimation()', 600);
  ding = $('#caption');
  type();
});

function type() {
  ding.html(caption.substr(0, clength++));
  if (clength < caption.length + 1) {
    setTimeout('type()', 180);
  } else {
    clength = 0;
    caption = '';
  }
}

function erase() {
  ding.html(caption.substr(0, clength--));
  if (clength >= 0) {
    setTimeout('erase()', 50);
  } else {
    clength = 0;
    caption = '';
  }
}

function cursorAnimation() {
  $('#cursor').animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 'fast', 'swing').animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 'fast', 'swing');
}
```

Comment: where do you call erase()? and what is caption

Comment: Edited. Pls. have a look. @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are different ways to do this.

Firstly I must say the way you use `setTimeout` is not the best. By putting the string expression into it you make the JS engine to parse the expression through `eval`. A slow and simply dangerous thing that must be evaded as much as possible; except it's really needed.

In this case you can simply pass a function as a parameter of `setTimeout` and it will work as well. So, `setTimeout(type, 180)`.

Now as I understand your code both `type()` and `erase()` are recursive functions that either call themselves or finish their execution after reaching the end. "Finish their execution after reaching the end" is exactly the branch of code you need so you just put there a call of erase.

```
} else {
    clength = 0;
    caption = '';
    erase();
}
```

Now maybe you want to save the possibility for your `type()` function to launch without the mandatory call of `erase()` in the end. In your case I would encapsulate it in a closure, like this:

```
function type(callback) {
    return function(){
        ding.html(caption.substr(0, clength++));
        if (clength < caption.length + 1) {
            setTimeout('type()', 180);
        } else {
            clength = 0;
            caption = '';
            if (callback != undefined) callback();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case your `type` function becomes a first class function, a function that generates other functions. When you call it with `type(erase)` it writes `callback` as `erase` and returns a function whose variable scope contains `callback` so it can call it as it was its own local variable.

If you call `type()` it creates a function with `callback` being undefined so nothing happens in this case.

**EDIT**:

```
function type(callback) {
    return function(){
        ding.html(caption.substr(0, clength++));
        if (clength < caption.length + 1) {
            setTimeout(type(callback), 180);
        } else {
            if (callback != undefined) callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is not clear to me. Some things: 
- invoking erase under else abruptly removes the text, so I dont get any effect here.
- In your "first class function", how should I call the type and erase function in my `ready` function?

Comment: `type(erase)();`

**invoking erase under else abruptly removes the text, so I dont get any effect here**

That's because you drop your `caption` and `clength` in `type()` so `erase` has nothing to work with and jumps right into the `else` block.

Comment: Didnt work. I called `type(erase)();` in the ready function. Also where is the erase invocation supposed to be in the "first class function"? You can just edit your answer how you think the code is supposed to be.

Comment: Check it, I added the snippet of code that works. The erase invocation is `callback()`. When you call `type(erase)` it returns a function that has `erase` as `callback`.

Comment: Awesome! Works now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS-only possible solution:

```css
.caption {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  animation-name: typing, cursor;
  animation-duration: 5s, 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(23, end), linear;
}

@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  
  20% {
    width: 0;
  }
  
  60% {
    width: 165px;
  }
  
  80% {
    width: 165px;
  }
  
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes cursor {
  from {
    border-right: 1px solid;
  }
  
  to {
    border-right: 1px transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="caption">My name is Hritik Gupta</span>
```

Comment: I dont want to use CSS for this. The typed character doesn't look as if being typed. Can you help me with the JS code?
For reference, try running your code snippet. You'll understand what I mean.